# An adjective which means “the father of a bride gives her away”?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, terminology

What adjective could I use to describe the typical ‘Western’ wedding custom, whereby the **father of the bride  gives his daughter away**? I need an adjective that describes this tradition, in order to distinguish it from weddings of other cultural traditions.

> Today, "giving the bride away" has a very different meaning. The bride's father accompanies her on her walk down the aisle to show approval of the groom. Centuries ago, fathers actually did give their daughters away to their future husbands, since females were property of their fathers
>   <sub>Wikipedia: [Weddings in the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weddings_in_the_United_States#Ceremony_and_Reception)</sub>

I am reluctant to use "European" because of some European exceptions, e.g. Frisian culture.

Would "Roman" or "Feudal"  be appropriate here? I found an answer on a Wikipedia article: [*Pater familias*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pater_familias) wherein the term "manus marriage" is used, I believe this  has the meaning I require. Would the Latin expression, *[manus marriage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manus_marriage)*, be understood by native speakers? Is it used today?

Comment: There are many different types of wedding in *Western* society. I assume you refer either to a Christian wedding, or a secular wedding which draws upon a Christian tradition; as opposed to a Muslim, Hindu or Buddhist wedding. I'm not sure there is a name which covers this. If I were needing to make the point I might say something like: *The couple surprised their Indian relatives by going for a western-style wedding at Rotherham register office.* Or you could say *secular*. But this question is as much about sociology as language.

Comment: I am talking culture, not religion here.  Going back to my Friesian example, such weddings are often Christian, but the father of the bride does not give her away- they couple arrive at the church together.  However, at many non-Christian weddings in the Western world, the father of the bride gives her away.  There are also a broad variety of cultural traditions within the Muslim world, too.

Comment: Around here a "Western" wedding is called a "wedding".

Comment: @Miner_Glitch Well there are plenty of weddings in Britain where the father of the bride plays no part. I heard of one recently where no guests were invited, and the only persons present were the bride, the bridegroom and the registrar. However they are *western* in the sense that they are quintessentially part of modern "western" society. They do not belong to any "eastern" tradition. Perhaps what we are discussing here is the meaning of the word "western" which clearly is a movable thing.

Comment: There really is no such thing as a *typical* western wedding. Even within western society there are too many variations. The only thing typical western weddings have in common is that they cost a lot of money. So how about *Expensive*?

Comment: Roman and Feudal would not be appropriate because the same tradition exists in Orthodox weddings.  What characteristics do the weddings you're asking about have other than the fact that there is at least one bride and a father who gives her away?    Can you give a sentence in which you would use it?

Comment: Possibly you could call this a "romanticized sale" --  i.e., a romanticized version of regarding the woman as a chattel, to be transferred from the ownership of her father to the ownership of her husband.

Comment: @Al Maki , when I suggested "Roman" I was bearing in mind the marriage laws of Augustus Caesar introduced around 18 BC, which are to a not insignificant extent a principal origin of the cultural tradition I am referring to.  As you noted, this tradition does exist also in Orthodox weddings, which is as expected given Orthodox culture would still be derived from Augustus.

Comment: I don't think everybody would understand "manus marriage" the way you think they would. Manus is not an English word, it's Latin for *hand*. I wouldn't say it's a typical description of a *western* wedding either. There are other cultures that have adopted the tradition of ‘giving away’ the bride too. But, admittedly, you have piqued my interest in your question.

Comment: I hope you don't mind the slight changes I have made, if you are happy with the expression *manus marriage* and you accepted the possibility of the  question being deleted then the edits shouldn't bother you. The original post was a little ambiguous, and the answers you received where not entirely appropriate, I think users will be more motivated in answering now. Good luck!

Comment: @Miner_Glitch - For your interest, there's an exact term for it in Hindu weddings - **[Kanyadan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanyadan)**.

Comment: You might want to consider clarifying the question a little bit, it seems that users have possibly misunderstood your request, which my edit is partly to blame for. You might want to specify that you want an adjective that distinguishes European/Australian/US weddings (traditions) from those in Asia, and the Middle East.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the idiomatic expression **"white wedding"**, that is a *traditional*, ​mostly Christian, ​marriage in a ​church or a temple (at which the woman who is getting ​married ​wears a ​white ​dress).

Comment: This is actually a really good answer to the question as I originally asked it, prior to moderation.

Comment: @Miner_Glitch it was your question, you could have edited, clarified it as you saw fit. Your original question had *What adjective should be used to describe a typical "Western" wedding (i.e. where the father of the bride gives her away)*, i.e. means "that is", if instead you meant "for example" then it is written as e.g. Anyway, glad to see you received an answer that helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try ***"Old-Hollywood-Movie*** **Type"** wedding.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the term that fits the context you are describing is ***[patriarchal](http://hubpages.com/relationships/Sexual-Morality-Traditional-Marriage-Gay-Marriage)***:

*Patriarchal  Traditional Marriage:*

> - The orthodox view of sexual ethics has been in the context of the patriarchal traditional marriage of the past few millennia -- a relationship of ownership and domination of a husband over his wife. Remnants of traditional marriage are still commonly found in modern American marriages, and elsewhere.
> - ***In a traditional wedding ceremony, the father “gives away” the bride to the groom.*** This property transaction is, I speculate, a remnant of the practice of the father selling his daughter to the groom for a bride price, such as for a negotiated number of goats or ounces of gold.
> - It is still common for the bride to take her husband's last name. Some Americans still use quaint dominant-subordinate expressions like “head of the household” in reference to a husband as a matter of right of position lording it over his wife. It was less than 40 years ago that American law gave a woman the right to bank credit in her own name.

(hubpages.com)

Comment: I am not totally adverse to that, since it does, for example, distinguish my Friesian case (I suspect Patriarchy vs Matriarchy is why the Angles and Friesians broke up).  However, it does not adequately distinguish from those non-European cultures which are also patriarchical.

Comment: @Minet_Glitch - what do you mean by "it does not adequately distinguish from those non-European cultures which are also patriarchical."?

Comment: Josh61 - The term "Patriarchical Traditional Marriage" is too broad in that it would also refer to traditional marriages in other patriarchical cultures, e.g. patriarchical cultures from Asia.  I am seeking to refer only to that cultural heritage which includes the tradition which has as its root the Roman law principle of Manus Marriage.

Comment: @Miner_Glitch - I doubt that in Asia "traditional patriarchal marriages" don't imply "giving the bride" to the groom. As the extract suggests the practice is probably connected to the rituals of a 'property transaction', common to many cultures.,

Comment: Josh61 - but if it "don't imply" that, it makes your suggested term even less relevant.  It appears the edit done by  Mari-Lou A has misled you as to what I am asking for.

Comment: @Miner_Glitch - may be I am misundending your point here.

Comment: I believe the OP wants an adjective that distinguishes European/Australian/US weddings (traditions) from those in Asia, and the Middle East. Maybe my edit didn't focus enough attention on this aspect. I've suggested that he might want to edit and clarify his question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - not sure what OP is after, here. I think the custom of 'giving the bride away' is common to many cultures, women have been considered ( and still are somewhere) "private property" in many places around the world.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'Bestowing bride'. We in India use the hindi term 'Kanyadaan' which is also popularly described as 'bestowing bride' or 'gifting the bride to the groom'

Answer (score -1):

A ***Wagner-Mendelssohn*** type wedding.

Comment: That suggests the type of music, not really what I'm after.

Comment: @Miner_Glitch: I'm not sure what you're after, but the music is the first distinguishing feature that comes to mind.

Comment: @Ricky +1 Nice catch.

Comment: Wagner-Mendelssohn wedding sounds like an announcement in the *Times*.